# how to aumatically select menu item in the base template for each section of the main page in django template system?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a couple of sections in my project with different page templates, say A.html, B.html, C.html. They all extend base.html. I want to show a navigation menu on the base.html (page header) and show the current page item in a different way, ie. class='selected' appended for the A link on A.html page.

How can I achieve this effect? Is it possible to get the name of the template from the base template?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the name of current item in the context, and pass it to the template. In the template, check whether it is the selected item:

```
<div class='nav'>
    <a {% ifequal selected 'about' %}class='selected'{% endifequal %} href='/about/'>About</a>
    ...
</div>
```

For other solutions, you may refer to this post [Django templates - can I set a variable to be used in a parent template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228898/django-templates-can-i-set-a-variable-to-be-used-in-a-parent-template)

Comment: I don't want to use context for that. it should be possible in  the template system..